Error on RecurrenceTable with two variables
I am trying to simulate a second order filter unit step response with the RecurrenceTable instruction in Mathematica. There's a problem with the second-order equation.
My code below is not working:
Second order filter Unit Step Response with recurrence table

a = 1.996
b = -0.996
c = 1.992 10^-5
d = 0
e = 0

Filter2ndOrder = RecurrenceTable[{
x[n + 1] == 1, 
y[n + 1] == a y[n] + b y[n - 1] + c x[n + 1] + d x[n] + e x[n - 1], 
x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2, x[1] == 1, y[1] == 0}
, y, {n, 0, 1000, 10}, 
DependentVariables -> {x, y}]

ListPlot[Filter2ndOrder, PlotRange -> All]

The code I used on MATLAB is the following one (there is no RecurrenceTable in MATLAB), but a simple For loop do the job easily :
N = 10000 ;
x = ones(N,1); % unit step response x(n) = 1 whatever n (for n=1 to N)
y = zeros(N,1);% we are defining y matrix = 0 at startup

a = 1.996;
b = -0.996;
c = 1.992E-5;
d = 0.;
e = 0.;

for n = 3:N
    y(n) = a*y(n-1) + b*y(n-2) + c*x(n) + d*x(n-1) + e*x(n-2);
end

Some remarks :

x is equal to 1 for every n value (unit step),
I wish to reproduce into Mathematica what I did easily into MATLAB
Nevermind if it is with RecurrenceTable or For loop, Do loop or
anything else
The plot looks like the following one :



After replacing x[n + 1] == 1 by x[n + 1] == x[n] your code works well. x[n + 1] == 1 is not a recurrence eqution.

Here is the result of ar in 14.0 on Windows 10:{2., 1.95111, 1.90461, 1.86038, 1.81832, 1.77831, 1.74026, 1.70407, \ 1.66965, 1.63691, 1.60577, 1.57615, 1.54799, 1.5212, 1.49571, \ 1.47148, 1.44843, 1.4265, 1.40565, 1.38582, 1.36696, 1.34902, \ 1.33195, 1.31572, 1.30029, 1.28561, 1.27164, 1.25836, 1.24573, \ 1.23372, 1.22229, 1.21142, 1.20109, 1.19126, 1.18191, 1.17301,

1.16455, 1.15651, 1.14886, 1.14158, 1.13466, 1.12807, 1.12181, .11586, 1.11019, 1.10481, 1.09968, 1.09481, 1.09017, 1.08576, 1.08157, 1.07758, 1.07379, 1.07018, 1.06675, 1.06349, 1.06038, \ 1.05743, 1.05462, 1.05195, 1.04941, 1.047, 1.0447, 1.04251, 1.04044, \ 1.03846, 1.03658, 1.03479, 1.03309, 1.03147, 1.02993, 1.02847, \ 1.02708, 1.02575, 1.0245, 1.0233, 1.02216, 1.02108, 1.02004, 1.01906, \ 1.01813, 1.01725, 1.0164, 1.0156, 1.01484, 1.01411, 1.01342, 1.01277, \ 1.01214, 1.01155, 1.01098, 1.01045, 1.00994, 1.00945, 1.00899, \ 1.00855, 1.00813, 1.00773, 1.00736, 1.007, 1.00665}.

Also T1 = 2; T2 = 2; Te = 0.01; a = T1/T2; b = (Te - T1)/T2; c = 1 - Te/T2; is the correct syntax.

What is asked that is answered in my comment. That's all.

It is not a good practice to substantially change a question, not indicating the edit. All my previous comments are made to the original question before its edit.

With two initial conditions for x, the recurrence relation for x should be at least second order.

There are three syntax error in your code: (i) x[n + 1] == 1 which is not a recurrence equation (RE) shoud be replaced by x[n+1]==x[n]; (ii) with respect to x this is a first order RE , so x[1] == 1 should be excluded; (iii)both REs include x[n+1], only one RE shoud include the term.
The following works well.
a = 1.996;b = -0.996;c = 1.992  10^-5;d = 0;e = 0;
Filter2ndOrder =  RecurrenceTable[Reduce[{x[n + 1] == x[n], 
y[n + 1] ==  a  y[n] + b  y[n - 1] + c  x[n + 1] + d  x[n] + e  x[n - 1], 
x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2, y[1] == 0}, {x[n + 1], y[n + 1]}], 
y, {n, 0, 100, 10}, DependentVariables -> {x, y}]


{2., -17.6429, -36.5122, -54.6381, -72.05, -88.7759, -104.843,  -120.276, -135.102, -149.342, -163.022}


Thank you so much, user64494, for all your help and time. I could never have solved this problem on my own. Well done !
